# c# : int.Parse not working correctly

Tags: c#, try-catch

I implemented the following method in c#, to check if the user-entered number is a 10 digit number or not. It is working fine for an input number of upto 10 digits. But, when I enter a number of greater than 10 digits it prints **Given string does not represent a number** instead of **The length of the Contact No. is not 10**

I know that I can do the same thing using regex-matching, but I just want to do it by using throwing exceptions. Any help is appreciated.

```
    public static bool CheckContactNo(string ContactNo)
    {
        try
        {
            int Number = int.Parse(ContactNo);
            int IsZero = ContactNo.Length == 10 ? 1 : 0;
            //Console.WriteLine("{0}",IsZero);
            int somenum = 1/ IsZero;
            return true;
        }
        catch(DivideByZeroException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The length of the Contact No. is not 10");
            return false;
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Given string does not represent a number");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using exception handling as control flow is costly at runt time, and, more importantly, difficult to read, since that's not their purpose. 

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 32-bit `int` cannot hold 10 full digits, its [max value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is `2,147,483,647`.

In other words, `int.Parse` detects that your int would overflow, and gives that error.

Answer (score 2):

Int32.MaxValue is 2,147,483,647 . You won't be able to parse numbers larger than int.maxvalue.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Joachim's answer (where the solution is to use `Int64`), I would also not use exceptions (like DivZero) to control flow in that way, instead prefer to use validations like [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to determine whether the value is numeric:

```
if (contactNo.Length != 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The length of the Contact No. is not 10");       
}
else
{
    long contactLong;

    if (Int64.TryParse(ContactNo, out contactLong)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Given string does not represent a number");
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Int64` instead of int

Answer (score 0):

This(2,147,483,647) is the maximum value for Int32 so int.Parse internally checks for this 
You could use Int64.Parse

Comment: You are the fifth person to give the same response.